# How do I access a Kindle's core files?

Tags: kernel, hardware

If I mount a Kindle (on my Ubuntu machine), it shows me various files and databases related to books, metadata, etc.

But I don't see the actual OS and its files - am I seeing them and not realizing it, or are those hidden somehow? How do I access the actual OS?

(What I'm after is to find the log files. The last update messed up my device, and I'm hoping there is a record of the previous firmware's version somewhere, so I can roll back.)

Comment: You can't even do that on android. And the Swindle is even more closed, so unless you jail-break it you can't do it. The solution is not on the Gnu/Linux machine. Incidentally my mums HD fire, has recently reset it self, it how asks us to register it (for the spyware), we tried several times, even created a new account. It looks like we did it, it shows us lots of advertisements, then we try to use it, and we are back at the start. It just goes around is circles.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor That is very sad... I haven't jail broken it because I've never understood the benefit. Agree with your "swindle" comment, but then again, I don't know that there is anything "better" than it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't even do that on android. And the Swindle is even more closed, so unless you jail-break it you can't do it. The solution is not on the Gnu/Linux machine.